# If every element $a \in A$ is even, then why is it false that some $a \in A$ is even?

Tags: logic

Suppose $A$ is a set.

> If every element $a \in A$ is even, then some $a \in A$ is even.

Why is this a false statement?

Comment: Consider $A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not true for the empty set. Also, that is the only set it is not true for.

You may try to prove the latter (and the former too actually), then you will perfectly understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false, as $A = \emptyset$ is a counterexample: Every element of $\emptyset$ is even (as there aren't any elements), but there is no element of $\emptyset$ which is even.

The following statement is true:

> Suppose, $A$ is a non-empty set. If every $a \in A$ is even, then some $a \in A$ is even.